# $A,B \in \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ $ABA-BAB=I$ and $A^2B+B^2A=O$ $A,B$ are invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B$ be two matrices with $A,B \in \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ and $ABA-BAB=I$ and $A^2B+B^2A=0$. Prove that $A,B$ are invertible matrices.

Comment: Why (-1) dear downvoter? thanks! is it to easy?

Comment: I think it's because you haven't given any context. Please show your working so far :)

Comment: what work? I tried some methods, some particularization... but nothing... it's not very useful to write 2-3 A4 pages with blank work

Comment: Well, show what you've tried since you've tried some methods. I only know that you've got nothing now that I've been annoyed that you didn't tell me you've got nothing.

Comment: @ Shaun:  in re. your use of the words "we":  you and who else?

Comment: @RobertLewis I've wondered the same when mathematicians write 'we', so I mostly stick to 'one' and 'I'.

Comment: That's a fair point: I've edited the comment :)

Comment: @ Shaun:  launds for that.  And thanks.  I don't mind saying that *I* sometimes get annoyed when individual users speak/write as if for the totality of MSE participants.  I mean, who asked *me* what I think?  Regards, RKL.

Comment: @RobertLewis It was a bit presumptuous. Sorry :)

Comment: @ Git Gud:   well, the "we" here is a somewhat different usage than the mathematical "we have" *und so weiter*.  Anyway, I tend to use both "we" and "I" in writing math, depending on the context, my mood, etc. ;-)!

Comment: @ Shaun:  no need to apologize.  And thanks again! ;-)!

Comment: @Iuli Sorry to ask: Does this statement hold for sure and you want a proof, or do you want to see if it is possible to prove it (and you are not sure whether it holds true or not)?

Comment: Why somebody wants to close this topic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set  $X:=\begin{bmatrix} A & B\\ -B & A\end{bmatrix}$ and $Y:=\begin{bmatrix} BA & AB\\ -AB & BA\end{bmatrix}$.

Note that $XY=\begin{bmatrix} ABA-BAB & A^2B+B^2A\\ -B^2A-A^2B & -BAB+ABA\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} I & \bf 0\\ \bf 0 & I \end{bmatrix}$.

So $XY=YX=\begin{bmatrix} BA^2-AB^2 & BAB+ABA\\ -ABA-BAB & -AB^2+BA^2\end{bmatrix}$.

You can now use any entry of the last matrix above to conclude. Taking, for instance, the entry $(1,2)$ you can find $BAB+ABA=\bf 0$ and one of the hypothesis is $ABA-BAB=I$. Summing yields $2ABA=I$ and so both $B$ and $A$ are invertible.

Comment: This is quite awesome.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Unfortunately I deserve no credit. I just emulated the idea from [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/492902/55235) answer. And if user1551 came up with it, my hat is off to him.

Comment: Choosing entry $(1,2)$ yields $2ABA = I$.

Comment: @ Gig Gud:  nice one, +1.  Hope dinner was good!

Comment: Thanks! nice idea :D a good night!

Comment: @RobertLewis With spicy ketchup anything goes.

Answer (score 0):

We can do better. Indeed, according to Git Gud post, $BA=1/2A^{-1}$ and consequently $AB=BA$. Then $BAB=-1/2 I$ implies $BA=-1/2B^{-1}$. Finally, the relations are $A=-B$ and $2A^3+I=0$.

EDIT: Some have ridiculous habit of removing a point without saying why, and without giving their name. This gives a very bad image of (pseudo ?) mathematicians.